# Does an observer in the rest frame see a finite laser pulse shorter?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Consider a finite pulse moving with some group velocity away from an observer. Does the observer in the rest frame actually see a shorter pulse due to Lorentz contraction?

Comment: See a shorter pulse than *what*?

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to "see" a laser pulse? And also, what do you mean by the "length" of a laser pulse? If you mean that you normally "see" a laser pulse by letting it shine on your detector (camera, hand, etc.) and that the "length" of the laser pulse is simply its time of duration multiplied by the speed of light, then it will appear longer or shorter *relative to the laser that generated the pulse* depending on your (observer's) speed *relative to the origin*. So, if you are travelling towards the pulse, the relativistic Doppler effect will narrow/shorten the pulse.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect